# Cycling through point shapes when more than 6 factor levels

Tags: r, ggplot2

When using the aesthetic mapping `shape` within `geom_point`, I get the following message when the number of factors present exceeds 6:

"The shape palette can deal with a maximum of 6 discrete values because more than 6 becomes difficult to discriminate; you have 15. Consider specifying shapes manually. if you must have them."

I tend to agree with the principle of limiting the number of distinct shapes, however when *using shape in combination with color* this should not be a problem.

Is there an elegant way to get ggplot to cycle through shapes, i.e. setting symbol7 = symbol1 etc? Right now it simply omits the points with factor level > 6.

Comment: Some might argue that combining shape with color makes the problem worse, not better. Regardless, the solution, as the warning states, is to specify the shapes manually, using `scale_shape_manual`.

Comment: @joran : how could it be worse than not being able to tell which curve belongs to which legend item, because the colors are too close?

Comment: My point was that if using many shapes is bad because it's difficult to tell large numbers of them apart, then using many shapes in combination with multiple colors will be even harder to distinguish.

Comment: @joran : true, but the idea here is to use _few_ shapes in combination with colors. i.e. repeating the same 6 symbols in different colors.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[image: plot symbols]

as you can see you have many possibilities for shapes. When you reach >6 you have to set the number manually, in this way:

```
    ggplot(data=dat1, aes(x=x, y=y,group=method,shape=method,color=method))+
    geom_point() +
    scale_shape_manual(values=seq(0,15))
```

In this way you will have no warnings and you will get the corresponding symbols on the graph

**Update**

As Luchonacho pointed out there are many new shapes available. Remember that if you want to set them using a loop do not use `aes()` as it would temporally keep in memory the last plotting reference (i.e. only the last looped input) and plot only that one.

[image]

Comment: Interesting. Is there a way to cycle through them?

Comment: If I understood your question you could envelope the above code lines around a simple for-loop and change the numbers in `scale_shape_manual(values=seq(i,i+10))` supposing for example that i is your looping variable

Answer (score 8):

The shapes in the existing answer are outdated. These are the current ones:
[image]

As you can see, they are all called by numbers. If you use a symbol (as in the other answer), an error occurs.

If you have not so many more than 6, then it is easy to choose them manually. For example, if you have 10 lines, one alternative is:

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x,y, colour = z)) + 
    geom_line() + scale_shape_manual(values = c(4,8,15,16,17,18,21,22,3,42))
```

Answer (score 6):

As pointed out by the other answers you need to use `scale_shape_manual`.

To **repeat** the desired symbols you can simply use `rep(x, times)`. For example if you want to repeat the filled out symbols 14 to 18 (see luchonacho answer for a list of symbols), you can use the following:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x,y, colour = z)) + geom_point()
    scale_shape_manual(values = rep(15:18, 5))
```

This will repeat the symbols 15 to 18 five times so it is enough for 20 different values of `z`.

Answer (score 1):

When you have more than 6 factors it becomes difficult to differentiate in the final graph. I used a combination of colors and shapes to get the intended effect for 15 factors dividing them into 3 colors and 5 symbols with the following code after the geom_ lines

```
 +scale_color_manual(values=c(rep("#00BFCC",5), rep("#E7AA00",5), rep( "#FC4E07", 5)))  
+scale_shape_manual(values=rep(0:4, 3))
```

Also note that the values can be changed with different colors and shapes.

Hope this helps.