# Assigning 40 shapes or more in scale_shape_manual

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame with more than 40 factor levels and I would like to assign different shapes for each level. However, as shown in the [scale_shapes_table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813278/cycling-through-point-shapes-when-more-than-6-factor-levels) of `ggplot2`, I can assign only 26 of them and some `!`,`"`,`#` and so on.

[image]

But I know that in python or jmp you can assign many shapes (like asteriks, left triangle ,right triangle, rectangle etc.). Is it also possible also in `ggplot2`?

```
data=data.frame(gr=seq(1,40), x1=runif(40), y1=runif(40))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=data,aes(x=x1,y=y1,shape=factor(gr),col=factor(gr)))+
  geom_point(alpha = 0.3,size=4,stroke=1.4) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(0:40))
```

[image]

Comment: You should consider whether using so many shapes is an effective visualization. Perhaps your data can be divided into a smaller number of categories? Also consider facets.

Comment: @neilfws yes I considered that and I need many shapes as possible:)

Comment: @Alexander You did not consider enough. It's extremely challenging and time consuming for the human brain to distinguish 40 shapes. You are creating a bad visualization.

Comment: @Roland ı dont think using the facet is the only solution. some people doesnt want to see separated data. in my point it is much easier to tracking the shape rather than using the same 8 shapes with different colors. thanks anyway for your comment.

Comment: I never said that using facets is the only solution. I said using 40 symbols is a bad solution, it's most likely what Tufte calls [chartjunk](http://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1003833#s9). You should ask at stats.stackexchange.com for better ways of visualizing your data (they love visualization questions).

Comment: While the OP's graph may be ugly... I'm still interested in this question because I'm looking for a way to include a greater diversity of symbols on my plot (e.g, carat-right, caret-left symbols for "sideways triangles" - AND have them show up in the legend (seems difficult using geom_label).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A large set of symbols is available using the `emojifont` package with Font Awasome (see the complete list [here](http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/)). More details are given [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emojifont/vignettes/emojifont.html).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(emojifont)
set.seed(1234)
symbls <- c('fa-github', 'fa-binoculars', 'fa-twitter', 'fa-android', 'fa-coffee', 
'fa-cube', 'fa-ambulance','fa-check','fa-cutlery','fa-cogs','fa-dot-circle-o','fa-car',
'fa-building','fa-fire', 'fa-flag','fa-female','fa-gratipay','fa-heart','fa-magnet',
'fa-lock','fa-map','fa-puzzle-piece','fa-shopping-cart','fa-star','fa-sticky-note',
'fa-stop-circle-o','fa-volume-down','fa-anchor', 'fa-beer','fa-book','fa-cloud',
'fa-comment','fa-eject','fa-chrome','fa-child','fa-bomb', 'fa-certificate',
'fa-desktop','fa-fire-extinguisher','fa-diamond')
idx <- order(symbls)
fa <- fontawesome(symbls)
k <- length(fa)
data=data.frame(gr=factor(fa, levels=fa[idx]), x1=runif(k), y1=runif(k))
data$gr <- factor(data$gr, levels=fa[idx])

ggplot(data, aes(x1, y1, colour=gr, label=gr)) +
    xlab(NULL) + ylab(NULL) + geom_point(size=-1) +
    geom_text(family='fontawesome-webfont', size=6, show.legend=FALSE) +
    theme(legend.text=element_text(family='fontawesome-webfont')) +
    scale_colour_discrete("Points",guide=guide_legend(override.aes=list(size=4)))
```

[image]

**Warning**: if you want to use the code in Rstudio, first reassign the graphing device as follows:

```
devtools::install_github("coatless/balamuta")
library("balamuta")
external_graphs()
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. does this emjifont has math sybolds too? couldn't find them? Or similar to base symbols but different shapes?

Comment: @Alexander If you need to use Rstudio, see the update of my post. I use this solution when plots are not displayed in Rstudio.

Answer (score 11):

Would using a combination of 5 or 10 distinct shapes with distinct colors sufficient to distinguish the 40 points work better?  I see these as being visually easier to differentiate the 40 elements than using/resorting to unusual symbols.

```
ggplot(data=data,aes(x=x1,y=y1, shape=factor(gr), col=factor(gr)))+
 geom_point(alpha = 0.5, size=4, stroke=1.4) +
 scale_shape_manual(values=rep(c(0:2,5:6,9:10,11:12,14), times=4))
```

[image]

Or take advantage of the 5 unique shapes that take fill colors.

```
ggplot(data=data,aes(x=x1,y=y1, shape=factor(gr), fill=factor(gr), col=factor(gr)))+
 geom_point(alpha = 0.5, size=4, stroke=1.4) +
 scale_shape_manual(values=rep(c(21:25), times=8))
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Maybe use **gr** as labels, using *ggrepel*, easier to find a number than comparing shapes:

```
library(ggrepel)

ggplot(data = data, aes(x = x1, y = y1, label = gr))+
  geom_point() +
  geom_label_repel()
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, but still very cluttered. If technically possible I might use an interactive graph which allows the reader to highlight one or two categories by assigning them colors. But of course, I'm in doubt that mapping to 40 categories is important. I might also try to aggregate categories.

Comment: @Roland `shiny` came to my mind when I read the post, but I think OP wants static plots. Yes, this needs more grouping with colours.