# R: How to extend this polygon at the first and last x ticks with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotate, xscale

I have this plot code:

```
ggplot() +
  annotate("rect",xmin=as.Date("1900-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d"), xmax=as.Date("2020-12-31", "%Y-%m-%d"), 
           ymin=bind.fine[1,3], ymax=bind.fine[1,4], alpha=0.4, fill="gray70")+
  geom_hline(yintercept=7188.349, linetype = "dashed",col="red",size=2)+
   geom_pointrange(data=bind.fine, mapping=aes(bind.fine[1,1], 
    y=bind.fine[1,2], ymin=bind.fine[1,3], ymax=bind.fine[1,4]),
     width=0.2, size=2, color="blue", fill="white", shape=16)+
      geom_line(data=bind.fine,aes(x,y),col="black")+
       theme_bw()+
        xlab("")+ylab("Biomass (t.)")+
         scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 8400))+
          theme( panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
           panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = 
            element_line(colour = "black"),text=element_text(size=24))+
             geom_text(aes(fine.w[900,1], 7500, label="Anchovy"),size=7)
```

my data frame `bind.fine` ( only first 300 rows) is:

```
                   x           y    upper    lower
1    1902-01-01 7188.349226 4904.093 8344.867
2    1902-02-01          NA       NA       NA
3    1902-03-01          NA       NA       NA
4    1902-04-01          NA       NA       NA
5    1902-05-01          NA       NA       NA
6    1902-06-01          NA       NA       NA
7    1902-07-01          NA       NA       NA
8    1902-08-01          NA       NA       NA
9    1902-09-01          NA       NA       NA
10   1902-10-01          NA       NA       NA
11   1902-11-01          NA       NA       NA
12   1902-12-01          NA       NA       NA
13   1903-01-01          NA       NA       NA
14   1903-02-01          NA       NA       NA
15   1903-03-01          NA       NA       NA
16   1903-04-01          NA       NA       NA
17   1903-05-01          NA       NA       NA
18   1903-06-01          NA       NA       NA
19   1903-07-01          NA       NA       NA
20   1903-08-01          NA       NA       NA
21   1903-09-01          NA       NA       NA
22   1903-10-01          NA       NA       NA
23   1903-11-01          NA       NA       NA
24   1903-12-01          NA       NA       NA
25   1904-01-01          NA       NA       NA
26   1904-02-01          NA       NA       NA
27   1904-03-01          NA       NA       NA
28   1904-04-01          NA       NA       NA
29   1904-05-01          NA       NA       NA
30   1904-06-01          NA       NA       NA
31   1904-07-01          NA       NA       NA
32   1904-08-01          NA       NA       NA
33   1904-09-01          NA       NA       NA
34   1904-10-01          NA       NA       NA
35   1904-11-01          NA       NA       NA
36   1904-12-01          NA       NA       NA
37   1905-01-01          NA       NA       NA
38   1905-02-01          NA       NA       NA
39   1905-03-01          NA       NA       NA
40   1905-04-01          NA       NA       NA
41   1905-05-01          NA       NA       NA
42   1905-06-01          NA       NA       NA
43   1905-07-01          NA       NA       NA
44   1905-08-01          NA       NA       NA
45   1905-09-01          NA       NA       NA
46   1905-10-01          NA       NA       NA
47   1905-11-01          NA       NA       NA
48   1905-12-01          NA       NA       NA
49   1906-01-01          NA       NA       NA
50   1906-02-01          NA       NA       NA
51   1906-03-01          NA       NA       NA
52   1906-04-01          NA       NA       NA
53   1906-05-01          NA       NA       NA
54   1906-06-01          NA       NA       NA
55   1906-07-01          NA       NA       NA
56   1906-08-01          NA       NA       NA
57   1906-09-01          NA       NA       NA
58   1906-10-01          NA       NA       NA
59   1906-11-01          NA       NA       NA
60   1906-12-01          NA       NA       NA
61   1907-01-01          NA       NA       NA
62   1907-02-01          NA       NA       NA
63   1907-03-01          NA       NA       NA
64   1907-04-01          NA       NA       NA
65   1907-05-01          NA       NA       NA
66   1907-06-01          NA       NA       NA
67   1907-07-01          NA       NA       NA
68   1907-08-01          NA       NA       NA
69   1907-09-01          NA       NA       NA
70   1907-10-01          NA       NA       NA
71   1907-11-01          NA       NA       NA
72   1907-12-01          NA       NA       NA
73   1908-01-01          NA       NA       NA
74   1908-02-01          NA       NA       NA
75   1908-03-01          NA       NA       NA
76   1908-04-01          NA       NA       NA
77   1908-05-01          NA       NA       NA
78   1908-06-01          NA       NA       NA
79   1908-07-01          NA       NA       NA
80   1908-08-01          NA       NA       NA
81   1908-09-01          NA       NA       NA
82   1908-10-01          NA       NA       NA
83   1908-11-01          NA       NA       NA
84   1908-12-01          NA       NA       NA
85   1909-01-01          NA       NA       NA
86   1909-02-01          NA       NA       NA
87   1909-03-01          NA       NA       NA
88   1909-04-01          NA       NA       NA
89   1909-05-01          NA       NA       NA
90   1909-06-01          NA       NA       NA
91   1909-07-01          NA       NA       NA
92   1909-08-01          NA       NA       NA
93   1909-09-01          NA       NA       NA
94   1909-10-01          NA       NA       NA
95   1909-11-01          NA       NA       NA
96   1909-12-01          NA       NA       NA
97   1910-01-01          NA       NA       NA
98   1910-02-01          NA       NA       NA
99   1910-03-01          NA       NA       NA
100  1910-04-01          NA       NA       NA
101  1910-05-01          NA       NA       NA
102  1910-06-01          NA       NA       NA
103  1910-07-01          NA       NA       NA
104  1910-08-01          NA       NA       NA
105  1910-09-01          NA       NA       NA
106  1910-10-01          NA       NA       NA
107  1910-11-01          NA       NA       NA
108  1910-12-01          NA       NA       NA
109  1911-01-01          NA       NA       NA
110  1911-02-01          NA       NA       NA
111  1911-03-01          NA       NA       NA
112  1911-04-01          NA       NA       NA
113  1911-05-01          NA       NA       NA
114  1911-06-01          NA       NA       NA
115  1911-07-01          NA       NA       NA
116  1911-08-01          NA       NA       NA
117  1911-09-01          NA       NA       NA
118  1911-10-01          NA       NA       NA
119  1911-11-01          NA       NA       NA
120  1911-12-01          NA       NA       NA
121  1912-01-01          NA       NA       NA
122  1912-02-01          NA       NA       NA
123  1912-03-01          NA       NA       NA
124  1912-04-01          NA       NA       NA
125  1912-05-01          NA       NA       NA
126  1912-06-01          NA       NA       NA
127  1912-07-01          NA       NA       NA
128  1912-08-01          NA       NA       NA
129  1912-09-01          NA       NA       NA
130  1912-10-01          NA       NA       NA
131  1912-11-01          NA       NA       NA
132  1912-12-01          NA       NA       NA
133  1913-01-01          NA       NA       NA
134  1913-02-01          NA       NA       NA
135  1913-03-01          NA       NA       NA
136  1913-04-01          NA       NA       NA
137  1913-05-01          NA       NA       NA
138  1913-06-01          NA       NA       NA
139  1913-07-01          NA       NA       NA
140  1913-08-01          NA       NA       NA
141  1913-09-01          NA       NA       NA
142  1913-10-01          NA       NA       NA
143  1913-11-01          NA       NA       NA
144  1913-12-01          NA       NA       NA
145  1914-01-01          NA       NA       NA
146  1914-02-01          NA       NA       NA
147  1914-03-01          NA       NA       NA
148  1914-04-01          NA       NA       NA
149  1914-05-01          NA       NA       NA
150  1914-06-01          NA       NA       NA
151  1914-07-01          NA       NA       NA
152  1914-08-01          NA       NA       NA
153  1914-09-01          NA       NA       NA
154  1914-10-01          NA       NA       NA
155  1914-11-01          NA       NA       NA
156  1914-12-01          NA       NA       NA
157  1915-01-01          NA       NA       NA
158  1915-02-01          NA       NA       NA
159  1915-03-01          NA       NA       NA
160  1915-04-01          NA       NA       NA
161  1915-05-01          NA       NA       NA
162  1915-06-01          NA       NA       NA
163  1915-07-01          NA       NA       NA
164  1915-08-01          NA       NA       NA
165  1915-09-01          NA       NA       NA
166  1915-10-01          NA       NA       NA
167  1915-11-01          NA       NA       NA
168  1915-12-01          NA       NA       NA
169  1916-01-01          NA       NA       NA
170  1916-02-01          NA       NA       NA
171  1916-03-01          NA       NA       NA
172  1916-04-01          NA       NA       NA
173  1916-05-01          NA       NA       NA
174  1916-06-01          NA       NA       NA
175  1916-07-01          NA       NA       NA
176  1916-08-01          NA       NA       NA
177  1916-09-01          NA       NA       NA
178  1916-10-01          NA       NA       NA
179  1916-11-01          NA       NA       NA
180  1916-12-01          NA       NA       NA
181  1917-01-01          NA       NA       NA
182  1917-02-01          NA       NA       NA
183  1917-03-01          NA       NA       NA
184  1917-04-01          NA       NA       NA
185  1917-05-01          NA       NA       NA
186  1917-06-01          NA       NA       NA
187  1917-07-01          NA       NA       NA
188  1917-08-01          NA       NA       NA
189  1917-09-01          NA       NA       NA
190  1917-10-01          NA       NA       NA
191  1917-11-01          NA       NA       NA
192  1917-12-01          NA       NA       NA
193  1918-01-01          NA       NA       NA
194  1918-02-01          NA       NA       NA
195  1918-03-01          NA       NA       NA
196  1918-04-01          NA       NA       NA
197  1918-05-01          NA       NA       NA
198  1918-06-01          NA       NA       NA
199  1918-07-01          NA       NA       NA
200  1918-08-01          NA       NA       NA
201  1918-09-01          NA       NA       NA
202  1918-10-01          NA       NA       NA
203  1918-11-01          NA       NA       NA
204  1918-12-01          NA       NA       NA
205  1919-01-01          NA       NA       NA
206  1919-02-01          NA       NA       NA
207  1919-03-01          NA       NA       NA
208  1919-04-01          NA       NA       NA
209  1919-05-01          NA       NA       NA
210  1919-06-01          NA       NA       NA
211  1919-07-01          NA       NA       NA
212  1919-08-01          NA       NA       NA
213  1919-09-01          NA       NA       NA
214  1919-10-01          NA       NA       NA
215  1919-11-01          NA       NA       NA
216  1919-12-01          NA       NA       NA
217  1920-01-01 2403.022635       NA       NA
218  1920-02-01 2764.279655       NA       NA
219  1920-03-01 3118.651814       NA       NA
220  1920-04-01 3401.920612       NA       NA
221  1920-05-01 3469.692188       NA       NA
222  1920-06-01 3283.350691       NA       NA
223  1920-07-01 2920.907169       NA       NA
224  1920-08-01 2574.737216       NA       NA
225  1920-09-01 2548.457720       NA       NA
226  1920-10-01 2810.503547       NA       NA
227  1920-11-01 3221.798666       NA       NA
228  1920-12-01 3753.523309       NA       NA
229  1921-01-01 4373.636039       NA       NA
230  1921-02-01 5048.858112       NA       NA
231  1921-03-01 5738.330768       NA       NA
232  1921-04-01 6377.445140       NA       NA
233  1921-05-01 6759.857238       NA       NA
234  1921-06-01 6528.134158       NA       NA
235  1921-07-01 5703.192412       NA       NA
236  1921-08-01 4699.759376       NA       NA
237  1921-09-01 3996.911725       NA       NA
238  1921-10-01 3502.690101       NA       NA
239  1921-11-01 3349.507151       NA       NA
240  1921-12-01 3634.630428       NA       NA
241  1922-01-01 4095.045631       NA       NA
242  1922-02-01 4630.976092       NA       NA
243  1922-03-01 5124.174439       NA       NA
244  1922-04-01 5494.897853       NA       NA
245  1922-05-01 5478.366362       NA       NA
246  1922-06-01 4655.641053       NA       NA
247  1922-07-01 3331.883504       NA       NA
248  1922-08-01 2335.298604       NA       NA
249  1922-09-01 1847.519826       NA       NA
250  1922-10-01 1715.883708       NA       NA
251 1922-11-01 1847.171    NA    NA
252 1922-12-01 2103.326    NA    NA
253 1923-01-01 2434.195    NA    NA
254 1923-02-01 2824.287    NA    NA
255 1923-03-01 3229.645    NA    NA
256 1923-04-01 3594.269    NA    NA
257 1923-05-01 3786.839    NA    NA
258 1923-06-01 3658.484    NA    NA
259 1923-07-01 3131.680    NA    NA
260 1923-08-01 2472.575    NA    NA
261 1923-09-01 2062.643    NA    NA
262 1923-10-01 2003.280    NA    NA
263 1923-11-01 2162.525    NA    NA
264 1923-12-01 2437.272    NA    NA
265 1924-01-01 2779.794    NA    NA
266 1924-02-01 3088.235    NA    NA
267 1924-03-01 3285.347    NA    NA
268 1924-04-01 3489.873    NA    NA
269 1924-05-01 3627.395    NA    NA
270 1924-06-01 3468.821    NA    NA
271 1924-07-01 2980.128    NA    NA
272 1924-08-01 2406.522    NA    NA
273 1924-09-01 2151.088    NA    NA
274 1924-10-01 2186.264    NA    NA
275 1924-11-01 2298.803    NA    NA
276 1924-12-01 2488.524    NA    NA
277 1925-01-01 2780.037    NA    NA
278 1925-02-01 3121.717    NA    NA
279 1925-03-01 3433.671    NA    NA
280 1925-04-01 3702.325    NA    NA
281 1925-05-01 3877.331    NA    NA
282 1925-06-01 3794.569    NA    NA
283 1925-07-01 3397.855    NA    NA
284 1925-08-01 2903.363    NA    NA
285 1925-09-01 2528.657    NA    NA
286 1925-10-01 2226.145    NA    NA
287 1925-11-01 2116.697    NA    NA
288 1925-12-01 2285.083    NA    NA
289 1926-01-01 2562.984    NA    NA
290 1926-02-01 2878.583    NA    NA
291 1926-03-01 3204.120    NA    NA
292 1926-04-01 3484.216    NA    NA
293 1926-05-01 3579.619    NA    NA
294 1926-06-01 3360.649    NA    NA
295 1926-07-01 2806.712    NA    NA
296 1926-08-01 2101.802    NA    NA
297 1926-09-01 1636.138    NA    NA
298 1926-10-01 1617.378    NA    NA
299 1926-11-01 1841.774    NA    NA
300 1926-12-01 2110.013    NA    NA
```

.....

the plot (previous code) is: [image]

The question is: how can extend (o reduct x axes) the dimension of gray rectangle, in correspondance of x-axes length ?

I tried with :
`scale_x_continuous(limits=c(as.Date(bind.fine[1,1]),as.Date(bind.fine[1356,1])))`
but the result is:

```
Error in as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied
```

the expected result is like this: 
[image]

Comment: `+scale_x_date(expand = c(0,0))`

Comment: ahhhhhh..very simple!!! Great...thank you!

Comment: you can also set xmin and xmax to be -Inf and Inf

Comment: What about the boat?  I am only half-kidding because apparently there is `emojifont` that can be incorporated to `ggplot2`. Made my day yesterday heh. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46803260/assigning-40-shapes-or-more-in-scale-shape-manual/46814238#46814238