# ggplot2 custom legend combining shape and fill

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to combine `fill` and `color` in a ggplot2 legend. Because there are several colors for the `x` axis, it seems logic that ggplot2 do not know which color to pick in the legend.

For exemple:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mpg, aes(fl, hwy)) +
    geom_point(aes(color = fl, shape = factor(year), fill = fl)) +
    scale_shape_manual(values = c("circle filled", "circle open"))
```

[image]

My goal would be to manually edit the `factor(year)` legend to look like this:

[image]

I played around the `guides()` function without success.

**Edit**:
Values for `shape` can be found by running `vignette("ggplot2-specs")`.

Answer (score 1):

you already had the nearly correct answer with the `scale_shape_manual`. But somehow the "circle filled" argument is invalid. Since i'm not sure where those values can be looked up, i took the values from a table of a similar question [(source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46803260/assigning-40-shapes-or-more-in-scale-shape-manual):
[image]

so with value 20 and  79 you can get the desired result.

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(fl, hwy)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = fl, shape = factor(year), fill = fl)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(16,79))
```

output:
[image]

Comment: This is a partial solution given that you can't set the color to e.g.: "grey" . However, this may not be actually possible so if there is no better answer I will accept yours.

Comment: Also, the shape `20` is smaller than the `79` which is notorious if the circles sizes are increased.

Comment: @mat alright i missed that it is necessary to have the legend in grey, this approach doesn't work then. Also i'll change the 20 to 16, then they should be at least same size. (not sure if 19 or 16 though)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here is a very roundabout way of making it look like the image above. Maybe someone else can come up with a more intuitive version:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(fl, hwy)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = fl, shape = factor(year), fill = factor(year))) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(16,79), guide = FALSE)  +
  scale_fill_manual("Year", values=c("grey","white"))+
                    guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = c(21,21),
                                                color = c("black", "black"))))
```

Output:
[image]